# SharePoint 2013 List: How to consolidate multiple lists items to get total/%reached?

Tags: 2013, list

I have a list in SharePoint 2013. Some of the items have the same Account#, and I'd like to be able to:

1. Add the duplicating Account#'s together to get their total $Amount
2. See how close that total is to a MaximumAmount ($AmountLeft and Percentage)
3. Get email notifications based on how close to the MaximumAmount (50%, 80%)

Is there a possible way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view group by account and then use CSR to extend group function.

```
 SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        Templates: {
            Group: function (ctx) {
                //your custom logic here
            }
        }
    });
```

In your custom group function, calculate the percentage and send email by /_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail.